# Unable to sync nativescript v3.x project in Telerik

Tags: angularjs, telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I have built a project in nativescript with angular version 4 and nativescript version 3. When I deploy on telerik using the app builder, I get the following error message:

```
the synced project is targetting tns-core-modules 3.1.1 and doesnt match the apps 2.5.1. to ensure correct behavior, please build to a new app package and deploy it
```

My package.json is using the following config:

```
"tns-core-modules": "next",
```

I want everything to be using 3.1.x. Does the Telerik app builder not support version 3 of nativescript yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Telerik's documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/index) 3.x is "Experimental".  It might be best to post to their forum or enter a support ticket with them for your specific issue.  They are very good at responding quickly.

Comment: Thanks, they responded: The answer given in the StackOverflow thread is correct. The Companion app is built using NativeScript 2.5.0 and your app should target the same version to work as expected. If your app targets a higher version of NativeScript it might still run and LiveSync correctly, however, you will most likely observe faulty behavior due to older versions of plugins installed in the Companion app.

Comment: Having said that, we are aware of the issues with NativeScript in Telerik Platform. This is why we are currently working on a different tool - NativeScript Sidekick. Unfortunately, it still does not offer a Companion app on which you can easily test your app, however, this feature is under consideration and might become available later on.